# What is the biggest punya in Hinduism?

Tags: karma, dharma, punyam

I know that Brahma hatya is the biggest sin in Hinduism.

But can anyone tell me about the biggest punya in Hinduism?

Comment: I guess it must be getting realised or working towards realisation or moksha is greatest Punya.

Comment: It can not be the greatest Punya because Moksha occurs only when all Punya and Paapa are dissolved@Optimus

Comment: Imo Vidya daan, Anna daan etc are virtuous deeds

Comment: There can be many great papas as well as many great punyas. I think there will not be a single one.

Comment: @Rickross but the dissolution itself happens because of Punya. If not what causes the dissolution. The confusion is because there are two kinds of Punya, one giving material pleasures and other giving Moksha and Eternal bliss. It is the second kind of Punya which causes Moksha, where first kind is dissolved. Also tag my name properly. I didn't get amy notification, I jist saw your comment 

Comment: I also did not get notification for your comment @Optimus

Comment: And no Moksha is beyond Punya and Papa both .. so Moksha is not the greatest Punya .. Moksha is going beyond Punya and Papa both

Answer (score 1):

**The answer is - there is no single answer for this question.**

As per different scriptures there maybe different outlook on the "biggest-puṇya".

Consider these excerpts.

### 1. Padma Maha-Purāṇa.

As per this, the biggest punya is the recital of the 18th Chapter of Srimad Bhagvad Geeta (told by Sri Krishna to Arjuna in the Mahabharata).

> #### Chapter 192 (Bhagavad-gītā Māhātmya),
>
> Uttara-Khaṇḍa, Padma-Purāṇa
>
> श्रीभगवानुवाच ।
>
> जपत्यष्टादशाध्याये गीतानां श्लोकपंचकम् । यत्पुण्येन च संप्राप्तं तव
> साम्राज्यमुत्तमम् ५३।
> **सर्वपुण्यशिरोरत्न** भूतेन त्वं स्थिरो भव । इति विष्णोर्वचः श्रुत्वा ज्ञातोपायं पुरंदरः ५४।
>
> > God Vishnu said -
> >
> > - 53-54. **He mutters five verses from the eighteenth chapter of the Gītā.** Due to that religious merit, **the crown gem of all (kinds of)
> >   religious merit**, he obtained your excellent sovereign empire. Be
> >   steady.

---

### 2. Shiva Mahā-Purāṇa

As per this, there maybe two different "biggest-puṇyas", one being the donation of food to the hungry, and other being recital of the Shiva Purāṇa.

- As per the [Chapter 11](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226556.html) of the Umā-Saṃhitā (Shiva Purāṇa 9.11), the general idea is emphasized on the superiority of the merit of food-donation to a hungry person.
- On the contrary to the above, as per the Verse 9.13.31-32, and in general the [Chapter 13](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226558.html), the general idea is given that recital of any Purāṇa, and Shiva Purāṇa specifically, is the biggest merit (Puṇya) of all.

---

## To Conclude -

Thus, on account of varying views on the "biggest-puṇyas" across the scriptures, we conclude that there is no "one-fits all answer" to the question posed.

Answer (score 1):

Read this story by Ramakrishna Paramahamsa

There was a famous astrologer in a village who mastered the art of astrology and palmistry. One day a farmer came to see him to know about his future. The astrologer examined the lines on his palm and found out that he might die in an accident that day. He did not like to reveal this to the farmer, as that would shock him. So he told the farmer to come and see him the next day. While the farmer was on his way home, there was heavy rain with thunder and lightning. The farmer took shelter in a temple of Lord Siva. When he saw the temple in ruins, he said to himself, ‘’if I was rich I would have renovated this temple.’ Then he started imagining the renovation and reconstruction of the temple. He was mentally constructing a new temple tower and a huge corridor, with carved pillars. But he was brought out of his dreamy status by the hiss of a cobra coming out of a hole in the broken wall.

His imagination of building a temple broke to pieces and he ran out of the dilapidated temple to save his life. The next moment a massive lightning struck the temple and the huge edifice, heavy stone pillars, all collapsed.. The farmer thanked the god for saving him and next day he met the astrologer. ‘’Your palm lines indicated a danger for your life yesterday. You should have accumulated great amount of punya by constructing a temple and so you are alive today. The farmer realised the mercy of god who had granted him his life for building an imaginary temple. Every good thought is considered by god as a good deed and one gets the benefit of it.

So do you see? Not necessarily the act, but pure and good thought and mind is the greatest Punya. Actions automatically follow thought. So think good about others and do good.